# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook 1.0.0 cause build error in Asp.net Core

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, facebook-access-token

I get this error, could you solve anyone?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1002  The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook 1.0.0 in project Project does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.   Project ...\project.json    50

```js
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-OAuthPracticeCore-01e81686-89d3-41dc-9598-9b5055e9f469",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you should edit your question and show the content of your project.json file

Comment: @JoeAudette Thanks a lot for the comment, I go this issue several times, and even after updating my VS 2015 to update 3 this issue is found when I add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook package from NuGet. I see here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html was the solution but now the VS project templates are different and get the above build error.

Comment: you need to upgrade your app from rc1 to 1.0.0 RTM, the latest tooling and project templates is for 1.0.0 not for rc1. you should view the announcements repo https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements to learn about changes you need to make to update from rc1

Comment: @JoeAudette Hi I have installation problem in one machine .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 does not get installed. In my office machine I have installed these tools. Now I am following the instruction https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html but get the error :  System.ArgumentException
The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder encoder, IOptions<SharedAuthenticationOptions>..